# AWS: How to find out whether someone is trying to mount the volume or copy the EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volumes

I have cloud monitoring turned on for my EBS Volumes that gives me metrics such as
BurstBalance, VolumeWriteOpS, VolumeQueueLengts etc.

I would like to find out how can I find out whether someone is trying to mount the volume or Copy the EBS volumes. Would I need to integrate with Cloud Trail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mount the volume

This is done from the instance. I don't think you can detect any mount attempts that after the EBS volume is already attached to the instance.

> Would I need to integrate with Cloud Trail?

You can use **CloudWatch Events** as well, don't need trial for that. For example, the event could be:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EBS Snapshot Notification"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "event": [
      "copySnapshot"
    ]
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EBS Volume Notification"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "event": [
      "attachVolume"
    ]
  }
}
```